# Batch Script assistance needed

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, batch-rename

Happy Friday Think-Tank!
I need some assistance with a Batch .BAT script. Specifically I need help with some "IF statement syntax"

I have a script that is renaming files. There are two files, one ending in four digits and the other ending in five digits. The files will be renamed with variables I have already pre-set earlier within my script.

So here is a scenario: We have two files in a directory located at

c:\Users\username\Desktop\test-dir

## There are two files within test-dir:

**file1.12345**

**file2.1234**

A four digit ending is one variable type (VAR1), whereas a file ending in five digits is another variable type (VAR2).

I need an if statement to:

a) read all the files(s) with the chosen directory (without using a wildcard if possible).
b) determine based on the number of digits after the "." which variable to use.
c) once making that determination rename the file with the appropriate variables.

The final re-naming convention is as so: yyyymmddtype.1234/12345

So basically it would use the datestamp variable I already created, the type variable I already created to be injected by the if statement, and append with the original ending digits of the file.

I know this seems like a lot, but I am more so a bash script guy. I have all the elements in place, I just need the if statement and what feels like a for loop of some kind to tie it all together.

Any help would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not the option you where asking for. Instead of iterating over the full list checking each file for extension conformance, iterate over a list of patterns that will filter file list, renaming matching files with the asociated "type"

`for %%v` will iterate over variable list, `for %%a` will split the content of the variable in pattern and type, `for %%f` will generate the file list, filter with `findstr` using the retrieved pattern and rename matching files with the corresponding "type"

Rename command is preceded with a `echo` to output commands to console. If the output is correct, remove the `echo` to rename the files.

```
@echo off

    rem Variables defined elsewhere
    set "folder=c:\somewhere"
    set "timestamp=yyyymmdd"

    rem Rename pattern variables in the form pattern;type
    set "var1=\.....$;type1"
    set "var2=\......$;type2"

    set "var1=\.[^.][^.][^.][^.]$;type1"
    set "var2=\.[^.][^.][^.][^.][^.]$;type2"


    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%v in ("%var1%" "%var2%") do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=;" %%a in ("%%~v") do (
        for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b "%folder%" ^| findstr /r /c:"%%~a"') do (
            echo ren "%folder%\%%~f" "%timestamp%%%~b%%~xf"
        )
    )

    endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "yyyymmdd=yyyymmdd"
set "VAR1=VAR1"
set "VAR2=VAR2"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d^|findstr /re ".*\....."') do echo(ren "%%~a" "%yyyymmdd%%VAR1%%%~xa"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d^|findstr /re ".*\......"') do echo(ren "%%~a" "%yyyymmdd%%VAR2%%%~xa"
```

remove `echo(` to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you then this will rename the two files using preset variables for each one:

```
for %%a in ("%userprofile%\Desktop\test-dir\*") do (
   if "%%~xa"==".12345" ren "%%a" "%variableA%-%variableB%%%~xa"
   ) else (
   ren "%%a" "%variableC%-%variableD%%%~xa"
   )
)
```